# X and Y are independent random variables with the same distribution

Tags: statistics

X and Y are independent random variables with the same distribution. If W=X+Y and Z=X-Y why are W and Z not independent?

Comment: At least for $X$ and $Y$ being constant random variables $W$ and $Z$ *are* independent...

Comment: The same is true for the Gauss distribution... So, there are nontrivial examples when they *are* independent.

Comment: @savick01 I don't quite understand how it can sometimes be independent and other times not. Can you maybe explain it in terms of covariance?

Comment: It's simple. It depends on the distribution of $X$ and $Y$. For the Dirac's delta or the Gauss distribution they are independent, but there are examples (see my answer) when they are not. The excercise is tricky, because the covariance will always be $0$, but it doesn't mean that the variables are independent. (If covariance is nonzero, they are dependent, but if it is zero, it doesn't already mean that they are independent!)

Answer (score 3):

We give an example that may make it clear why $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ need not be independent.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be (independent and) uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Suppose that $|X-Y|$ is "large" (bigger than $0.9$). Then it is *impossible* for $X+Y$ to be small (say less than $\frac{1}{2}$). So information about $X-Y$ ccan yield information about $X+Y$.

**Remark:** One could rewrite the above as $\Pr\left((|X-Y|\gt 0.9)\cap (X+Y\lt \frac{1}{2})\right)\ne \Pr(|X-Y|\gt 0.9)\Pr(X+Y\lt \frac{1}{2})$, but that would somewhat defeat the point of the example.

Comment: [offtopic] Why did you delete your answer to my question? It worked. I was about to comment

Comment: It didn't, it had a silly error. And since there was a live correct solution, there was no reason to correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed in the comments they may be independent. However, it is possible that they are not (depending on what $X,Y$ actually are).

Imagine $X=\pi_1:[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ being the projection onto the first coordinate and $Y=\pi_2:[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ - projection to the second coordinate ($[0,1]^2$ with Lebesgue measure is our probability space).

Now imagine the set $\{W\geq 1.5\}$. Its probability is $1/8$ (draw a picture). Take another set $\{Z\geq 0.5 \}$. Its probability is also $1/8$.

However the intersection of these sets is one point $\{X=1,Y=0.5\}$, so its probability is equal to $0$ (and it should be $1/8\cdot 1/8$ by the formula for independent variables).

Comment: In general how would you calculate the covariance of W and Z? I understand that in the end, Cov(W,Z) should equal 0 but how?

Comment: @user94378 Assuming $X$ and $Y$ have finite variance: $\def\E{\mathbb E}$ $$\mathrm Cov(W,Z)=\E(W\cdot Z) - \E W \cdot \E Z = \E(X^2-Y^2) - \E W \cdot \E(X-Y) =\\= \E(X^2) - E(Y^2) - \E W \cdot (\E X - \E Y) = 0 - \E W\cdot 0 = 0.$$

Comment: In the above I use the formula for covariance (first equality), then multiply: $(X+Y)(X-Y)=X^2-Y^2$, then use additivity of expected value, and finally the fact that $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution, so $\mathbb E X = \mathbb E Y$ and $\mathbb E X^2 = \mathbb E Y^2$ (in the meantime I use the technical assumption of finite variance, but it is not that important).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $X$ and $Y$ discrete RVs over $\mathbb{Z}_+$. The conditional probability of $Y$ knowing $Z$ is:
$$\Pr(W=w|Z=z)=\Pr(X=\frac{z+w}{2})\Pr(Y=\frac{w-z}{2})$$

However:
$$
\Pr(W=w)= \sum_{t=1}^\infty \Pr(X=t)\Pr(Y=w-t)
$$
So in general: 
$$\Pr(W=w|Z=z)\neq \Pr(W=w) $$

Answer (score 0):

For an even easier counterexample, let $X$ and $Y$ be iid Bernoulli rvs, so they each take the values 0 and 1. You can draw up tables for the distributions of $W$ and $Z$, and see that conditioning on the value of one of the two will always restrict the possible values of the other, thus refuting independence. For reference, the pairs are $(W, Z) \in \{(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, -1), (2, 0)\}$, and I'm ignoring the degenerate cases where the parameter for the Bernoulli distribution is 0 or 1.

Answer (score -1):

If two variables are independent, then they must have a covariance of 0.
$$
\begin{align}
Cov(W,Z) &= Cov\left((X+Y),(X-Y)\right)\\
Cov\left((X+Y),(X-Y)\right) &= E\left[(X+Y)(X-Y)\right] - \left[E(X+Y)\right]\left[E(X-Y)\right]\\
&= E(X^2 - Y^2) - \left[E(X) + E(Y)\right]\left[E(X) - E(Y)\right]\\
&= E(X^2) - E(Y^2) - E(X)^2 + E(Y)^2\\
&= \left[E(X^2) - E(X)^2\right] - \left[E(Y^2) - E(Y)^2\right]\\
&= Var(X) - Var(Y)
\end{align}
$$

Just because $X$ and $Y$ are independent does not mean that they have the same variance. For cases where they do not have the same variance, the covariance term is <> 0, and thus the sum and difference of two independent random variables is not necessarily itself independent.

Comment: 1. I already did the very same calculation in the comment below my answer. 2. Both variances are equal, because X and Y have the same distribution (as I already emphasised under the answer of Bertrand R).

Comment: I guess I was typing as you wrote your comment, as I didn't see it before I posted above. But you are correct in that I mentally blanked on the "same distribution" bit.